# How to get background and foreground color values from xrdb in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, colors, prompt, xrdb

As in how can I get the `*.foreground` color value obtained with `xrdb -query` assigned to a variable in the script.

I'm trying to get both background and foreground colors into two variables that will be passed to another program as parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, kinda. When using pywal we can import the colours from its cache, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "${HOME}/.cache/wal/colors.sh"
fg=$color7
bg=$color2
...
```

The catch is that this obviously won't work if wal's cache doesn't exist. But then one just need to reset the wallpaper with pywal to get the cache rebuilt.